# ng-multiselect-dropdown closing on selecting second item in drop down

Tags: angular, ng-multiselect-dropdown

In this drpdown after selecting first item(pune), when I click on second item(New delhi) to select, Dropdown got closed, It is multiselect dropdown. Below are me settings:

```
dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: "ID",
      textField: "text",
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      enableCheckAll: true,
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      allowSearchFilter: true,
      itemsShowLimit: 1,
      closeDropDownOnSelection: false
    };
```

When click on second item(New Delhi), it should select. But dropdown itself closing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jyothi I think you need to change `itemsShowLimit: 1` to itemsShowLimit: 3.

Hopefully this will work. Let me know :)

Comment: can you provide your code?

which package using for dropdown?

Comment: Hi andrewbyteforge, Thanks for your time, But its not working. I need to show only one item among selected.

Comment: Hi harshad, this is version I am using "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.10",

Comment: As what Jyothi said are you using the latest version ?